# Simple for loop not working

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've been teaching myself C++ these past few days using the book "C++ Primer Plus".
I've been making decent progress. But one of the execises has been giving me some trouble.

Here's what I should do:

Write a program that requests the user to enter two integers.The program should
then calculate and report the sum of all the integers between and including the two
integers. At this point, assume that the smaller integer is entered first. For example, if
the user enters 2 and 9, the program should report that the sum of all the integers
from 2 through 9 is 44.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;

   cout << "Please enter the first number: ";
   cin >> a;
   cin.get();

   cout << "Please enter the second number: ";
   cin >> b;
   cin.get();


   for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
   {
      c += i;       
   }

   cout << c;
   cin.get();
   return 0;

}
```

Whenever I run it, the result will be 2293673.
Funny thing is, I've done a google search, and the working programs I've found are basically the same as mine, except for the fact that those work and mine does not.

So my question: What the hell did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Srry for my english.

Comment: You have to initialise c `c = 0`;

Comment: Have you enabled compiler warnings? They can often help you find mistakes, including this one.

Comment: Note that you can compute the result directly `(b - a + 1) * (a + b) / 2`

Answer (score 15):

You have not initialized the variable c. It should be initialized to zero.

```
int c = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`c` is not initialized here:

```
int c;
```

so it has an *indeterminate value*, in your case since you want `c` to be the sum of your series it makes sense to initialize it to `0`:

```
int c = 0 ;
```

Enabling warning on your compiler should have caught this, using `-Wall` with `clang` gives me the following warning:

```
warning: variable 'c' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  c+=i;
  ^
```